# Displaying data from database using PHP in an ordered fashion

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to build a web page that has 6 rows of images. Each row has 4 images and each image has a caption right below it. So it goes something like this:

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

and so on.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        $image = $rows["image"];
        $text = $rows["text"];
        echo "<img class=images src=$image> <p  class=texts>$text</p>";
    }
}           
?>
```

Both classes are set to `display: inline-block`. The code prints out each image next to the text. The text should be below the image. I am trying to think of ways of displaying the images and the texts in the proper format, but I can't seem to think of any solutions at the moment. Anyone can give me some insight?

Comment: You could look up tables in HTML.

Comment: @BigScar If I make a table, how would that work? The while loop will print the image once, then go to the next row and print the text. The loop will loop again and print another image in the same row and print the text in the next row. This will keep on until I have more than 4 images in the same row and more than 4 texts in the same row.

Comment: Try display: block instead of inline-block

Comment: @NenadVracar If I try display: block, then each image and text will print on separate lines and not on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **only** the `wrapper` class with the `display: inline-block` rule

```
<?php
$resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        $image = $rows["image"];
        $text = $rows["text"];
        echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
        echo "<img class=images src=$image> </br> <p  class=texts>$text</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using divs.
The following code will add in a row ever

```
<?php
$resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
    $count = 0;
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        $num_in_row = 4; // Number of items you want in each row
        if($count % $num_in_row == 0){
            echo '<div class="row">'; // if the row already has 4 items, add a new row.
        }
        $image = $rows["image"];
        $text = $rows["text"];
        echo "<span class='wrapper'>";
        echo '<img class="images" src='.$image.'> <div class="texts">'.$text.'</p>';
        echo "</span>";
        if($count % $num_in_row == ($num_in_row-1)){
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $count++;
    }
} 
?>
```

That should give you a result that looks like the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wmqu3g2/1/)

Comment: I've edited the code. Basically it has a feature to add in a new row every time the count is a multiple of four. I haven't tried it yet, but let me know what you see and I'll reply when I get home